# Error on .tpl file

Tags: php, html, iframe

Im getting an error on Dreamweaver on line 27 ("{if $widgets.iframe_ad and...") and cant figure out the error.
I posted the complete code because its an .tpl code and i hope this help instead of just showing a piece of it containing the error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>{$seo.title}</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="{$seo.description}" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="{$seo.keywords}">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="{$seo.title}"/>
    {if $fb_image neq ''}
        <meta property="og:image" content="{$fb_image}" />
    {/if}

    <link href="{$baseurl}/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico">
    <link href="{$baseurl}/templates/trakt/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{$baseurl}/templates/trakt/css/colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--[if IE]>
        <link href="{$baseurl}/templates/trakt/css/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$baseurl}/templates/trakt/css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$baseurl}/js/tooltip.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$templatepath}/js/jquery.rating.css?r=2" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$templatepath}/css/foxycomplete.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <script> 
        var baseurl = '{$baseurl}';
        {if $widgets.iframe_ad and $widgets.iframe_ad.content and (not $loggeduser_id or $widgets.iframe_ad.logged)}
            var iframe_ad = true;
        {else}
            var iframe_ad = false;
        {/if}

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      {literal}
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#shadow").css("height", $(document).height()).hide();
            $(".lightSwitcher").click(function(){
               $("#shadow").toggle();
               if ($("#shadow").is(":hidden"))
                  $(this).html("lights off").removeClass("turnedOff");
                else
                  $(this).html("lights on").addClass("turnedOff");
            });

         });
      {/literal}
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$templatepath}/css/demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$templatepath}/css/elastislide.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$templatepath}/css/custom.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$templatepath}/js/modernizr.custom.17475.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$baseurl}/templates/trakt/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$baseurl}/templates/trakt/js/prettyPhoto/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$baseurl}/templates/trakt/js/jquery.featureList-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$baseurl}/templates/trakt/js/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$baseurl}/templates/trakt/js/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$baseurl}/templates/trakt/js/jquery.quicksand.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$templatepath}/js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$templatepath}/js/foxycomplete.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='{$templatepath}/js/jquery.rating.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='{$templatepath}/js/jquery.MetaData.js'></script>

    <!--GOOGLE FONTS-->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <!--/GOOGLE FONTS-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$baseurl}/js/scripts.js?r=18"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$baseurl}/templates/trakt/css/bootstrap.css?r=5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script>
        js_lang.like = '{$lang.like}';
        js_lang.dislike = '{$lang.dislike}';
        js_lang.facebook_error = '{$lang.unexpected_facebook_error}';
        js_lang.please_wait = '{$lang.please_wait}';
        js_lang.ticker = '{$lang.video_ticker}';
        js_lang.report_thanks = '{$lang.report_thanks}';
    </script>

    <link href="{$baseurl}/templates/trakt/css/style.css?1.1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{$templatepath}/style/color/cc3366.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    {if $global_settings.facebook}
        {literal}
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                    FB.init({
                    appId      : '{/literal}{$global_settings.facebook.app_id}{literal}',
                    status     : true, 
                    cookie     : true,
                    xfbml      : true,
                    oauth      : true
                });
        {/literal}

        {literal}

            };

            (function(d){
               var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
               js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
               js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
               d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
             }(document));
            </script>    
        {/literal}
    {/if}

    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div id="header-wrapper">
        <div id="header" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="brand-text" href="/">{$sitename}</a>            
                    <div class="nav-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav pull-left">

                            {if $loggeduser_id}
                            <li class="dropdown{if $menu eq 'favorites' or $menu eq 'friends'  or $menu eq 'recommend-movies' or $menu eq 'recommend-shows' or $menu eq 'user'} boot-active{/if}">
                                {if $global_settings.seo_links eq 1}
                                    <a href="{$baseurl}/user/{$loggeduser_username}" class="dropdown-toggle"><b class="caret"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{$lang.my_account}</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        {if $modules.submit_links.status eq 1}
                                            <li><a href="{$baseurl}/submit">{$lang.submit_links}</a></li>
                                        {/if}
                                        {if $modules.requests.status eq 1}
                                            {if $global_settings.seo_links eq 1}
                                                <li{if $menu eq 'requests'} class="boot-active"{/if}><a href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.requests}">{$lang.requests}</a></li>
                                            {else}
                                                <li{if $menu eq 'requests'} class="boot-active"{/if}><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=requests">{$lang.requests}</a></li>
                                            {/if}
                                        {/if}
                                        <li><a href="{$baseurl}/friends">{$lang.my_friends}</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.favorites}">{$lang.favorites}</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.recommend_shows}">{$lang.recommend_shows}</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.recommend_movies}">{$lang.recommend_movies}</a></li>
                                        {if $plugin_menus.user|@count neq 0}
                                            {foreach from=$plugin_menus.user item=plugin_menu}
                                                {if $plugin_menu.sub_menu_url and $plugin_menu.sub_menu_title and $plugin_menu.plugin}
                                                    <li><a href="{$baseurl}/plugin/{$plugin_menu.plugin}/{$plugin_menu.sub_menu_url}">{$plugin_menu.sub_menu_title}</a></li>
                                                {/if}
                                            {/foreach}
                                        {/if}
                                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="popUp('#settings_form');">{$lang.settings}</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{$baseurl}/logout">{$lang.logout}</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                {else}
                                    <a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=user&profile_username={$loggeduser_username}" class="dropdown-toggle"><b class="caret"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{$lang.my_account}</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        {if $modules.submit_links.status eq 1}
                                            <li><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=submit">{$lang.submit_links}</a></li>
                                        {/if}
                                        {if $modules.requests.status eq 1}
                                            {if $global_settings.seo_links eq 1}
                                                <li{if $menu eq 'requests'} class="boot-active"{/if}><a href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.requests}">{$lang.requests}</a></li>
                                            {else}
                                                <li{if $menu eq 'requests'} class="boot-active"{/if}><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=requests">{$lang.requests}</a></li>
                                            {/if}
                                        {/if}
                                        <li><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=friends">{$lang.my_friends}</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=favorites">{$lang.favorites}</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=recommend_shows">{$lang.recommend_shows}</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=recommend_movies">{$lang.recommend_movies}</a></li>
                                        {if $plugin_menus.user|@count neq 0}
                                            {foreach from=$plugin_menus.user item=plugin_menu}
                                                {if $plugin_menu.sub_menu_url and $plugin_menu.sub_menu_title and $plugin_menu.plugin}
                                                    <li><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=plugin&plugin={$plugin_menu.plugin}&plugin_menu={$plugin_menu.sub_menu_url}">{$plugin_menu.sub_menu_title}</a></li>
                                                {/if}
                                            {/foreach}
                                        {/if}
                                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="popUp('#settings_form');">{$lang.settings}</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=logout">{$lang.logout}</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                {/if}
                            </li>
                            {/if}

                            {if $modules.tv_shows.status eq 1 or $modules.movies.status}
                                <li class="dropdown{if $menu eq 'new-shows' or $menu eq 'new-movies'} boot-active{/if}">
                                    {if $global_settings.seo_links eq 1}
                                        {if $modules.tv_shows.status eq 1}
                                            <a href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.new_episodes}" class="dropdown-toggle"><b class="caret"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{$lang.new_videos}</a>
                                        {else}
                                            <a href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.new_movies}" class="dropdown-toggle"><b class="caret"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{$lang.new_videos}</a>
                                        {/if}
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            {if $modules.tv_shows.status eq 1}
                                                <li><a href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.new_episodes}">{$lang.new_episodes}</a></li>
                                            {/if}
                                            {if $modules.movies.status eq 1}
                                                <li><a href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.new_movies}">{$lang.new_movies}</a></li>
                                            {/if}
                                        </ul>
                                    {else}
                                        {if $modules.tv_shows.status eq 1}
                                            <a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=new-shows" class="dropdown-toggle"><b class="caret"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{$lang.new_videos}</a>
                                        {else}
                                            <a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=new-movies" class="dropdown-toggle"><b class="caret"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{$lang.new_videos}</a>
                                        {/if}
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            {if $modules.tv_shows.status eq 1}
                                                <li><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=new-shows">{$lang.new_episodes}</a></li>
                                            {/if}
                                            {if $modules.movies.status eq 1}
                                                <li><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=new-movies">{$lang.new_movies}</a></li>
                                            {/if}
                                        </ul>
                                    {/if}
                                </li>
                            {/if}

                            {if $modules.tv_shows.status eq 1}
                                {if $global_settings.seo_links eq 1}
                                    <li class="dropdown{if $menu eq 'tv-shows' or $menu eq 'show' or $menu eq 'episode' or $menu eq 'tv-tag'} boot-active{/if}"><a href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.tv_shows}" class="dropdown-toggle" ><b class="caret"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{$lang.tv_shows}</a>
                                {else}
                                    <li class="dropdown{if $menu eq 'tv-shows' or $menu eq 'show' or $menu eq 'episode' or $menu eq 'tv-tag'} boot-active{/if}"><a href="{$baseurl}/?menu=tv-shows" class="dropdown-toggle"><b class="caret"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{$lang.tv_shows}</a>
                                {/if}
                                    {if $tv_categories or $plugin_menus.tv_shows|@count neq 0}
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        {foreach from=$tv_categories key=id item=val}
                                            {if $global_settings.seo_links eq 1}
                                                <li><a href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.tv_tag}/{$val.perma}">{$val.name}</a></li>
                                            {else}
                                                <li><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=tv-tag&tag={$val.perma}">{$val.name}</a></li>
                                            {/if}
                                        {/foreach}
                                        {if $plugin_menus.tv_shows|@count neq 0}
                                            {foreach from=$plugin_menus.tv_shows item=plugin_menu}
                                                {if $plugin_menu.sub_menu_url and $plugin_menu.sub_menu_title and $plugin_menu.plugin}
                                                    {if $global_settings.seo_links eq 1} 
                                                        <li><a href="{$baseurl}/plugin/{$plugin_menu.plugin}/{$plugin_menu.sub_menu_url}">{$plugin_menu.sub_menu_title}</a></li>
                                                    {else}
                                                        <li><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=plugin&plugin={$plugin_menu.plugin}&plugin_menu={$plugin_menu.sub_menu_url}">{$plugin_menu.sub_menu_title}</a></li>
                                                    {/if}
                                                {/if}
                                            {/foreach}
                                        {/if}
                                        </ul>
                                    {/if}
                                </li>
                            {/if}

                            {if $modules.movies.status eq 1}
                                {if $global_settings.seo_links eq 1}
                                    <li class="dropdown{if $menu eq 'movies' or $menu eq 'watchmovie' or $menu eq 'movie-tag'} boot-active{/if}"><a href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.movies}" class="dropdown-toggle"><b class="caret"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{$lang.movies}</a>
                                {else}
                                    <li class="dropdown{if $menu eq 'movies' or $menu eq 'watchmovie' or $menu eq 'movie-tag'} boot-active{/if}"><a href="{$baseurl}/?menu=movies" class="dropdown-toggle"><b class="caret"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{$lang.movies}</a>
                                {/if}
                                    {if $movie_categories or $plugin_menus.movies|@count neq 0}
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        {foreach from=$movie_categories key=id item=val}
                                            {if $global_settings.seo_links eq 1}
                                                <li><a href="{$baseurl}/{$routes.movie_tag}/{$val.perma}">{$val.name}</a></li>
                                            {else}
                                                <li><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=movie-tag&tag={$val.perma}">{$val.name}</a></li>
                                            {/if}
                                        {/foreach}
                                        {if $plugin_menus.movies|@count neq 0}
                                            {foreach from=$plugin_menus.movies item=plugin_menu}
                                                {if $plugin_menu.sub_menu_url and $plugin_menu.sub_menu_title and $plugin_menu.plugin}
                                                    {if $global_settings.seo_links eq 1} 
                                                        <li><a href="{$baseurl}/plugin/{$plugin_menu.plugin}/{$plugin_menu.sub_menu_url}">{$plugin_menu.sub_menu_title}</a></li>
                                                    {else}
                                                        <li><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=plugin&plugin={$plugin_menu.plugin}&plugin_menu={$plugin_menu.sub_menu_url}">{$plugin_menu.sub_menu_title}</a></li>
                                                    {/if}
                                                {/if}
                                            {/foreach}
                                        {/if}
                                        </ul>
                                    {/if}    
                                </li>
                            {/if}



                            {foreach from=$pages key=page_id item=page_data}
                                {if $global_settings.seo_links eq 1}
                                       <li class="{if $page_data.children|@count}dropdown{/if}{if $menu eq 'page'} boot-active{/if}">
                                           <a href='{$baseurl}/pages/{$page_data.permalink}' {if $page_data.children|@count}class="dropdown-toggle"{/if}>
                                               {if $page_data.children|@count}<b class="caret"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{/if}{$page_data.title}
                                           </a>
                                           {if $page_data.children|@count}
                                               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                   {foreach from=$page_data.children key=child_id item=child}
                                                       <li><a href="{$baseurl}/pages/{$child.permalink}">{$child.title}</a></li>
                                                   {/foreach}
                                               </ul>
                                           {/if}
                                       </li>
                                   {else}
                                       <li class="{if $page_data.children|@count}dropdown{/if}{if $menu eq 'page'} boot-active{/if}">
                                           <a href='{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=page&permalink={$page_data.permalink}' {if $page_data.children|@count}class="dropdown-toggle"{/if}>
                                               {if $page_data.children|@count}<b class="caret"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{/if}{$page_data.title}
                                           </a>
                                           {if $page_data.children|@count}
                                               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                   {foreach from=$page_data.children key=child_id item=child}
                                                       <li><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=page&permalink={$child.permalink}">{$child.title}</a></li>
                                                   {/foreach}
                                               </ul>
                                           {/if}
                                       </li>
                                   {/if}
                            {/foreach}
                            <!--
                            {if $modules.submit_links.status eq 1}
                                {if $loggeduser_id}
                                    {if $global_settings.seo_links eq 1}
                                        <li{if $menu eq 'submit'} class="boot-active"{/if}><a href="{$baseurl}/submit">{$lang.submit_module}</a></li>
                                    {else}
                                        <li{if $menu eq 'submit'} class="boot-active"{/if}><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=submit">{$lang.submit_module}</a></li>
                                    {/if}
                                {else}
                                    <li{if $menu eq 'submit'} class="boot-active"{/if}><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="popUp('#popup_login');">{$lang.submit_module}</a></li>
                                {/if}
                            {/if}-->


                            {if $plugin_menus|@count neq 0}

                                {foreach from=$plugin_menus key=main_key item=plugin_menu_top}
                                    {if $main_key neq 'user' and $main_key neq 'tv_shows' and $main_key neq 'movies'}
                                        {if $plugin_menus[$main_key]|@count eq 1}
                                            {foreach from=$plugin_menus[$main_key] item=plugin_menu name=plugin_loop}    
                                                {if $global_settings.seo_links eq 1}
                                                    <li class="dropdown{if $menu eq 'plugin' and $plugin eq $plugin_menu.plugin} boot-active{/if}">
                                                        <a href="{$baseurl}{$plugin_menu.full_url}" class="dropdown-toggle">{$plugin_menu.main_menu_title}</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                {else}
                                                    <li class="dropdown{if $menu eq 'plugin' and $plugin eq $plugin_menu.plugin} boot-active{/if}">
                                                        <a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=plugin&plugin={$plugin_menu.plugin}&plugin_menu={$plugin_menu.sub_menu_url}" class="dropdown-toggle">{$plugin_menu.main_menu_title}</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                {/if}
                                            {/foreach}
                                        {else}
                                            {foreach from=$plugin_menus[$main_key] item=plugin_menu name=plugin_loop}    
                                                {if $smarty.foreach.plugin_loop.iteration eq 1}
                                                    {if $global_settings.seo_links eq 1}
                                                        <li class="dropdown{if $menu eq 'plugin' and $plugin eq $plugin_menu.plugin} boot-active{/if}"><a href="{$baseurl}/{$plugin_menu.full_url}" class="dropdown-toggle"><b class="caret"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{$plugin_menu.main_menu_title}</a>
                                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    {else}
                                                        <li class="dropdown{if $menu eq 'plugin' and $plugin eq $plugin_menu.plugin} boot-active{/if}"><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=plugin&plugin={$plugin_menu.plugin}&plugin_menu={$plugin_menu.main_menu_url}" class="dropdown-toggle"><b class="caret"></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{$plugin_menu.main_menu_title}</a>
                                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    {/if}
                                                {/if}
                                                {if $global_settings.seo_links eq 1}
                                                    <li><a href="{$baseurl}/{$plugin_menu.full_url}">{$plugin_menu.sub_menu_title}</a></li>
                                                {else}
                                                    <li><a href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=plugin&plugin={$plugin_menu.plugin}&plugin_menu={$plugin_menu.sub_menu_url}">{$plugin_menu.sub_menu_title}</a></li>
                                                {/if}
                                            {/foreach}
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        {/if}
                                    {/if}
                                {/foreach}
                            {/if}
                        </ul>
                        {if $loggeduser_id eq 0}
                            <ul class="user signed-out">
                                <li><a href="/register" id="header-join">Join <strong>CookWarz</strong></a></li>
                                <li><a id="header-signin" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="popUp('#popup_login');">Sign in</a></li>
                            </ul>

                        {else}
                            <ul class="user signed-out">
                                <li><a href="{$baseurl}/user/{$loggeduser_username}" id="header-join">{$loggeduser_username}</a></li>
                                <li><a id="header-signout" href="{$baseurl}/index.php?menu=logout">{$lang.logout}</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        {/if}

                    </div>
                </div>            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="tips"></div>

    <div id="non-mashable">
```

can someone help me out? thanks

Comment: What's the error text?

Comment: And what template language is it?

Comment: php. and only says: "There is a syntax error on line 27." (the line i indicated)

Comment: This is not php, this is something that runs on php but have own syntax and rules.

Comment: i have posted the complete code if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Smarty. We can't say much about it. You need to start debugging, remove piece of condition and check results. Let's do a couples of test

1)

```
      {if $widgets.iframe_ad && $widgets.iframe_ad.content && (!$loggeduser_id || $widgets.iframe_ad.logged)}
            var iframe_ad = true;
        {else}
            var iframe_ad = false;
        {/if}
```

2)

```
        {if $widgets.iframe_ad && $widgets.iframe_ad.content}
            var iframe_ad = true;
        {else}
            var iframe_ad = false;
        {/if}
```

3) Remove this completely

```
        {if $widgets.iframe_ad && $widgets.iframe_ad.content}
            var iframe_ad = true;
        {else}
            var iframe_ad = false;
        {/if}
```

Have you still this error and is this in the same line?

Comment: i can confirm that is smarty

Comment: In the same line? Impossible. I suppose that Smarty is not working fine. This class is not passing varibles to template. It is really hard to help remote. We may look for an error long time in wrong place.